# ActionScript 3 Loader - swf disappears as soon as loader.width is set

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, size, loader

I'm using a Loader object to load an external swf:

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
stage.addChild(swfLoader);
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sometestfile.swf");

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete);

swfLoader.x = 240;
swfLoader.y = 210;

// Resize here?

swfLoader.load(bgURL);
function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace("File loaded");
}
```

This works fine until I try to set swfLoader.width or .height (as I do when I want to resize loaded images), but in this case the swf isn't displayed anymore. (It's running anyway as I receive traces from sometestfile.swf)

I've resolved my error, using swfLoader.content.width in the Complete event works.

Answer (score 2):

The loader will have zero width/height until the `COMPLETE` event fires, so wait until then to set the size. That may solve your problem.

Comment: i have the same problem. even if i set the width of 'Loader' instance when Event.COMPLETE fired, the swf disappears, any other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `stage.addChild(swfLoader);` and `swfLoader.x = 240;
swfLoader.y = 210;` and the height and width settings to the  loadProdComplete()